# I have two different parent menus in my main menu. the first parent menu with a dropdown is called "services" and the second dropdown is called

Tags: permalinks

I have two different parent menus in my main menu. The first parent menu with a dropdown is called "service" and the second parent menu with a dropdown is called "portfolio".  All the  child pages in the "service" menu  do not have the parent "service" in the URL of the child. For example, my child page italian showers, the URL used is simply "italian showers" with no mention of parent slug. However for my other parent "portfolio, I do put the parent slug, I do  use the parent slug in their respective child URL's, for example: portfolio/kitchen-renovation.
Is this ok?  My two parent pages "service" and "portfolio" are both not clickable. I originally was thinking that my "service" page is not actually a page, thus I did not put the slug in its child pages.  However I was not consistent because I forgot to follow this reasoning for the second parent.  Is this ok ? or will Google crawlers have an issue and penalize for SEO?